# Jboss tools configuration

Tags: jboss6.x

I have literally got confused about the below mentioned error:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui was unable to load class org.jboss.tools.jst.web.ui.internal.editor.jspeditor.JSPMultiPageEditor.**
```

Kindly help me in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

User JDK 1.6.0_05 or higher version for resolution.